# sql server 2008 application with wpf

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

I made an application using blend3 and SQL 2008 how can I make this application work on another PC with its database without install visual studio 2008 and how to install SQL 2008 in this case ? should I create new database or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install SQL2008 as default instance by choose 4 first check in installed feature then open reporting SQL and create new database for the same name you want to connect and then close all sql server from task manager then copy your database with the same name in the data folder in Microsoft SQL then start you application it will work .